# Executing commands with .desktop file does not work

Tags: command-line, launcher, .desktop

As a lefty playing Minecraft on the left hand is quite difficult due to some bugs. I wanted to make a workaround and when I start the minecraft launcher I also change my mouse from lefty mode to right hand mode and undoing this after having finished minecraft. This ussually does not require special rights. Here is the command I used for this. It worked pretty well.

```
xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3" && java -jar /home/blackbox/minecraft/launcher.jar && xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1"
```

After having made this command I wanted to place it in a .desktop file using gnome-desktop-item-edit. Wich worked fine until I wanted to execute it, nothing happened. I tried editing it with gedit, wich did not fix the problem. I also tried this just with

```
java -jar /home/blackbox/minecraft/launcher.jar
```

wich worked well.

The starter file looked like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[de_DE]=/home/blackbox/Dokumente/Programmshortcuts/Minecraft.png
Name[de_DE]=Minecraft Launcher
Exec= xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3" && java -jar /home/blackbox/minecraft/launcher.jar && xmodmap -e "pointer = 3 2 1" 
Comment[de_DE]=Minecraft Launcher
Name=Minecraft Launcher
Comment=Minecraft Launcher
Icon=/home/blackbox/Dokumente/Programmshortcuts/Minecraft.png
```

Comment: Why not wrap the commands in a script, and invoke the script from your `.desktop` file; or delete the space character after `Exec=`

Comment: just delete the space after Exec? I am gonna try this.

Comment: @waltinator sorry, but removing the space character after     Exec=  did not work. Im gonna try scripting this tomorrow.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to change `wich` to `which` and `ussually` to `usually`.